# How am I able to check which devices I'm interfacing with?

Tags: python, pyvisa, gpib

I work at a microwave technology company and part of my job is developing software to interface with the devices we use using Python, specifically PyVISA. I'm currently trying to write a program that interfaces with several different types of devices that have different command structures, so before executing the code, I want to be able to check which type of device is connected (all use GPIB addresses). How can I go about doing this? Right now I've been trying to send identity commands using nested try/except blocks as shown below because the different devices have different identify commands:

```
import pyvisa as visa

address = "GPIB0::6::INSTR"
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
device = rm.open_resource(address)

try:
    device.write("*IDN?")
    identity = device.read()
except visa.errors.VisaIOError:
    try:
        device.write("I")
        device.write("STB?")
        identity = device.read()
    except visa.errors.VisaIOError:
        try:
            device.write("ID?")
            identity = device.read()
        except visa.errors.VisaIOError:
            identity = "Unknown"

print(identity)
```

The device I'm testing the code with requires the `device.write("ID?")` version of this command, however instead of returning the identity, it's returning the numerical error code. Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the try/except block and see exactly where the device is failing. Since you are getting a numerical error code, I'm betting the error flow is as follows:

1. The script sends `*IDN?`
2. The device doesn't recognize this command and goes into an error state.
3. The script sends `I`
4. The device is already in an error state and doesn't respond.
5. The script queries `STB?`
6. The device reports the error it logged earlier.
7. The script interprets this response as the device name, even though it's the answer to the Status Byte query.

I find it's often better to write the identity function specifically for each device. For example: `def identity_dev1()` for a device that needs `*IDN?` and `def identity_dev2()` for a device that needs `I` and so on.

If you want a monolithic function that can do all of the above, you'll have to change the way you handle the status byte. Here's an example:

```
import pyvisa as visa

address = "GPIB0::6::INSTR"
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
device = rm.open_resource(address)

identity = None
try:
    device.write("*IDN?")
    identity = device.read()
except visa.errors.VisaIOError:
    device.write("*RST") # get rid of the error state and try something else
if not identity:
    try:
        device.write("ID?")
        identity = device.read()
    except visa.errors.VisaIOError:
        device.write("*RST") # get rid of error state
if not identity:
    identity = "Unknown"
```

In general it's better to not do extra try/except behavior over GPIB communication. Trying the wrong command takes extra time and can put the instrument in an error state. In the code above, I use the `*RST` command to leave the error state, but this isn't guaranteed to work on all tools.
print(identity)